# Shortcodes closing tags displaying as text in post pages in Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

In my site wordpress post pages these closing shortcode tags:

> [/vc_column_text][/vc_column][/vc_row]

are displaying as text.

How to remove this?

Answer (score 1):

Those are shortcodes from Visual Composer, check that your WYSIWYG hasn't encoded them through the visual editor instead of the text editor.

If you switch to text mode you may see something like:

```
%20%5B%2Fvc_column_text%5D%5B%2Fvc_column%5D%5B%2Fvc_row%5D
```

Simply replace it with what's rendered in your browser in text mode and save.